# ElasticSearch search with querystring and verify another field

Tags: python-3.x, elasticsearch

I need to translate the following SQL query to ES query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM SKILL 
WHERE SKILL.name LIKE 'text' and SKILL.type = 'hard'
```

I have tried the following using "elasticsearch" library for python3:

```
query = self.__es.search(index="skills", 
    body={"from" : skip, "size" : limit, 
    "query": 
        {"query_string": 
            {"query": 'text'}
        })
```

and this worked well. But now, I don't know how to check that the field 'type' is equal to 'hard'.
How can I do that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a bool query and in the "must" part put two queries, the full text one and a term one:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": [{
            "match": {
                "name": "this is a test"
            }
        }, {
            "term": {
                "type": "hard"
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

Before this you have to store the type property as a keyword field.